# Zend disableLayout() leaves html & body tags in output

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

could anyone take a look at this for me?

Problem: trying to output a csv on demand using Zend Framework. I want to avoid creating files on the system so I'm trying to use the same solution posted here:

[export csv in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136264/export-csv-in-zend-framework)

However - I'm getting 3 blank lines in the csv (and in any HTML source when viewed). I'm setting layouts in the ini file. I've tried putting the csv call earlier in the request cycle using preDispatch etc - but to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated
SWK

Comment: Are the head and body tags in the view or output from the controller?

Comment: they're in the layout.phtml
problem solved - user error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: (my apologies, this is quite frequent - it's like when you ask someone to come over to your desk to check your bug, and everything mysteriously works....)

I was closing php tags in a front controller plugin,thus generating new lines.